# My new mining settlement won't release any miners

Tags: godus

I just built a new mining settlement, and when I tap on the info circle it says the settlement has 5/3 miners (don't know how it did that) and that none of them are unemployed, but I never told the miners to do anything and I didn't get anymore mines, I still only have 10 - five each from my two other mining settlements. What happened?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what's going on here. Can you leash from the mining settlement to further away? If there's no space for new plots around the settlement you won't be able to sprog the miners out.

Comment: It will not let me leash followers from the settlement

Comment: Sounds like an unfortunate bug. You could try either expanding the town, but if that doesn't fix it you'd have wasted the extra belief. I'd just finger of god it to the ground and make it again.

Comment: I just had this happen to me. 4 builders were out building a new house when I squashed their homes into the mining town (bringing it from 4 capacity to 7). The town had 8/7 miners, but the numbers corrected after the builders finished the new house and moved in.

Comment: I logged in this morning and it seemed to have corrected itself. I sent out three miners to establish new mines and it works just fine. It may have been a bug, but I'm happy it's fixed now and that I didn't have to squish the whole town lol. Thanks for your assistance!